# Exclude fields before sending them on FileBeat

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, logstash, filebeat

I am sending logs with **FileBeat** to my **NIFI** server and I want to exclude some fields.

The logs are `json` and `.log`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can drop unwanted fields by using `drop_fields` processor.**

Refer to the [drop-fields-filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/5.4/drop-fields.html) doc for more details .

**Note** : You can't drop @prefixed fields, as they are always added by `filebeat`.